# WPF Richtextbox scroll one page up and down?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, richtextbox

i want to scroll page up and page down in wpf richextbox.i tried

```
var start = txtAppendValue.Selection.Start.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
               var end = txtAppendValue.Selection.End.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
               txtAppendValue.ScrollToVerticalOffset((start.Top + end.Bottom - txtAppendValue.ViewportHeight) / 2 + txtAppendValue.VerticalOffset);
```

But it continuously scroll each line beginning,if current offset value move to non visible area in richtextbox,i want to move page up or page down not a single line by line scroll.

**Note:** I also tried BringIntoView();

```
FrameworkContentElement fce = (textRange.Start.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
            if (fce != null)
            {
                fce.BringIntoView();
            }
```

its not working after i using `textrange.clearallproperties()`.Before that it works.

So,kindly let me know how to scroll pageup and pagedown?

Regards
Bala

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down one page:

```
EditingCommands.MoveDownByPage.Execute(null, yourRichTextBox);
```

Scroll up one page:

```
EditingCommands.MoveUpByPage.Execute(null, yourRichTextBox);
```